# Dynamically Adding Checkboxes to a Windows Form Only Shows one Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm sorry if this seems n00bish, but I have been searching for this for a few days now. I am attempting to dynamically add checkboxes to a windows form; however, only one checkbox appears on the form. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    box = new CheckBox();
    box.Tag = i.ToString();
    box.Text = "a";
    box.AutoSize = true;
    box.Location = new Point(10, i + 10);
    Main.Controls.Add(box);
}
```

As you can see I am adding the checkboxes via a for loop. I have tried messing with the location and enabling autosize in case they were somehow overlapping. The result is a single checkbox with text "a".

Comment: Try i * 50 instead of i + 10 which will only shift each box by 1 pixel

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually you already created a `CheckBox` but within the same point.

```
CheckBox box;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    box = new CheckBox();
    box.Tag = i.ToString();
    box.Text = "a";
    box.AutoSize = true;
    box.Location = new Point(10, i * 50); //vertical
    //box.Location = new Point(i * 50, 10); //horizontal
    this.Controls.Add(box);
}
```

Comment: Just a note to the OP, since there was some confusion with other answers...using `box = new CheckBox();` inside the loop instead of `CheckBox box = new CheckBox();` will work just as well.

Comment: Thank you for all of your quick responses! The problems were: the vertical distance between checkboxes was too small and the checkbox was not created within the for-loop.

Comment: @NominSim yes i know. thats why i said from my answer.

Comment: just follow my answer @cruskai239 you can see the difference

Comment: @cruskai239 There was only one problem...the other answers are incorrect in telling you that `box = new CheckBox();` was wrong. You are creating a `new CheckBox` every time you call **new**...

Comment: @spajce I know I just wanted to clarify some more so the OP didn't get confused. (I did +1 btw, I don't know why this deserved a DV as it is the proper answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In this case with help of dynamically assign Name property how to achive checkbox.checked property , in some other action like submit button. how can i get all check box is checked and which is created in loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance from every button you can make with your button or your event to make something like

```
 CheckBox myCheckedBox = (CheckBox)sender;
```